# Download file with c# WebClient

Tags: c#, .net, download, webclient

I'm trying to download a csv file using c# webclient from this link:

```
http://www.tase.co.il/_layouts/Tase/ManagementPages/Export.aspx?sn=none&enumTblType=allShares&Columns=noneColumns&Titles=noneTitles&action=1&SubAction=0&GridId=33&CurGuid={26F9CCE6-D184-43C6-BAB9-CF7848987BFF}&ExportType=3
```

This link works in my browser fine; however it doesn't work when I use the following code

```
WebClient ta = new WebClient();
ta.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://www.tase.co.il/_layouts/Tase/ManagementPages/Export.aspx?sn=none&enumTblType=allShares&Columns=noneColumns&Titles=noneTitles&action=1&SubAction=0&GridId=33&CurGuid={26F9CCE6-D184-43C6-BAB9-CF7848987BFF}&ExportType=3"), "s.csv");
```

I get an empty s.csv file size: 0 bytes.
What can I do?

Comment: When you try to download with that code... what? What happens?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do you get any exception? runtime error or something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Webclient downloadfileasync not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496850/webclient-downloadfileasync-not-working)

Comment: i dont get any exception i get empty s.csv file 0 bytes size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave your code a try and it returned the same results for me. I registered for the "DownloadProgressChanged" event and could see an exception:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Adding a **user-agent** header based on the following link resolves the problem:

[WebClient - The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794260/webclient-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-403-forbidden)

Answer (score -1):

This worked for similar issue:

```
WebClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0)");
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2496982/445533

*Edit:* Header example linked in accepted answer is not properly formatted and may fail.

Comment: You copied another answer as a new answer. IMO this should be a comment, not an answer. In addition, this seems to be the same kind of answer as the accepted one.

Comment: The accepted answer links to a header example that is not properly formatted. It failed in my case, while the one I posted worked. Hence this answer should be helpful.